# How to achieve old appearance of error message in material design TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, material-design, androidx

I am using **com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout**, and
trying to achive input field appearance like on the first image:

[image]

But it renders error message this way:

[image]

How to make it look like on the first picture?

**UPDATE:**
This is my xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivContactIcon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/gEnd"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tilHomePhone"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:hint="@string/profile_edit_hint_email"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
          style="@style/FontRoboRegularSizeMFontPrimaryOneLineMatchWrap"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: How do you get this error when entering some text into your email input, like the first picture or the second one ?

Comment: First picture is just a design made in photoshop

Comment: You need to call `setError()` on the `TextInputLayout`, not the `TextInputEditText`.

Comment: @MikeM. Wow! This is correct. Could you create answer instead of comment?

Comment: Actually, it's a common issue, and has been answered here before, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate instead. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And here you have options that you can have for the error.

`app:errorEnabled
setError(CharSequence)`

Comment: Error is enabled, but I want another appearance of it

Comment: drop the `style="@style/FontRoboRegularSizeMFontPrimaryOneLineMatchWrap"` and replace with `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"`